# (node:5321) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm taking a web dev course and currently coding along with this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhJwCD0tT5Y

I've made a github repository for the app which can be found here: https://github.com/JohnTarvis/node-pg-demo

The same error comes up whether I'm logged in as my normal user name, postgres or root.

this is the full error:

```
(node:6267) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/tarvis/Documents/sb-exercises/codealong/express-pg-intro-demo/VideoCode/pg-intro/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/home/tarvis/Documents/sb-exercises/codealong/express-pg-intro-demo/VideoCode/pg-intro/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/home/tarvis/Documents/sb-exercises/codealong/express-pg-intro-demo/VideoCode/pg-intro/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/tarvis/Documents/sb-exercises/codealong/express-pg-intro-demo/VideoCode/pg-intro/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
(node:6267) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6267) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is the db.js file

```
const { Client } = require("pg");

let DB_URI;

// If we're running in test "mode", use our test db
// Make sure to create both databases!
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
  DB_URI = "postgresql:///usersdb_test";
} else {
  DB_URI = "postgresql:///usersdb";
}

let db = new Client({
  connectionString: DB_URI
});

db.connect();

module.exports = db;
```

I've been googling this all day and most answers involve changing the code to add user credentials but that shouldn't be necessary if the instructor doesn't need to do this.  Is there some setting in postgres that I need to change?

A lot of answers involve changing the file pg_hba.conf

I cannot find this file on my system.  Do I need to add it?

(edit: located the file.  What do I need to change here?)

[image: pg_hba.conf]

Comment: And you didn't check the docs. you can connect DB in different ways (env, configure credentials in the program, string URI): https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting

Comment: most of the time in production string URI is used and it should be in the env.

Comment: @GolamrabbiAzad
But I should be able to fix this without altering the course code.  (this is all copy pasted from the school's website).  It's got to be something in the config files.  I found pg_hba.config and took a screenshot.  Can you see anything that I need to change?

Comment: I'm looking at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43532280/postgres-docker-node-js-password-authentication-failed-connection-refused and I'm thinking of setting everything to trust as the author did.

Comment: If you're using ```node.js``` ```dotenv``` and ```pg``` make sure you have ```require('dotenv').config();``` in your ```index.js```. This fixed this error once I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my hands, leaving the host unspecified (:///) in the connection URI with node pg is the same thing as connecting to 127.0.0.1.  And doing that requires an md5 hashed password, as specified in your pg_hba.conf.

There are many ways you get fix that.  You could change the connection URI to provide a URI-encoded password, you could change the URI to connect through the socket (`postgresql://%2Ftmp/userdb` or `postgresql://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fpostgresql/userdb`), you could change the 127.0.0.1/32 line of your pg_hba to `trust` or `ident` or something else that doesn't need a password.

Comment: I went ahead and changed every setting to trust and it works now.  I don't get the error but I suspect this isn't the way to do it in a real production environment.  For educational purposes it should be fine.  When I learn how to set up credentials I'll set it back to something more secure.